# Onclick <a> Runs controller method onload

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, controller

Hello I'm a total noob at Mvc and I can't seem to figure this one out myself.

I have some Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (Contribution ctrib in Model)
    {
        <p>@ctrib.Message.Content @ctrib.Likes @ctrib.Reports</p>
        <a href="#" onclick="@{((TimelinePageController)this.ViewContext.Controller).Like(Convert.ToInt32(ctrib.ID));};window.location.reload()">Like</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="@{((TimelinePageController)this.ViewContext.Controller).Report(Convert.ToInt32(ctrib.ID));};window.location.reload()">Report</a>
    }
}
```

I have a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Like(int ID)
{
    Contribution C = new Contribution(ID);
    C.likePost();
}

[HttpPost]
public void Report(int ID)
{
    Contribution C = new Contribution(ID);
    C.ReportPost();
}
```

I clearly see "Onclick" as function on the `<a>` but it activates on page load.

Also whenever I press one of the 2 `<a>`s both of them trigger the amount of times there are contributions in the Model. I think that has to do with the foreach but that is my only way of accumulating contributions.

If anyone could point out my mistake or help me that would be lovely.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem ? can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

I would let the controller handle the reload of the pages by redirecting to the main action of the page you were in.  Here's a small sample for your Like action. The report one should be very similar.

The view :

```
<a href="/YourController/Like/@ctrib.ID">Like</a>
```

The controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public void Like(int ID)
{
    Contribution C = new Contribution(ID);
    C.likePost();
    RedirectToAction("ActionName")
}
```

Hope that help!